# How to maintain original array order of locally scoped item array?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am trying to display the values from an array of objects into the DataTable in two different  pages based on condition, for example, **If the country is the USA then display it on 1st page or if the country is Sweden then display it in another page  ** and when I try to read the index it is showing wrong index value .

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
        v-model="selected"
        v-bind:headers="headers"
        v-bind:items="items"
        select-all
        v-bind:pagination.sync="pagination"
        item-key="name"
        class="elevation-1"
      >
      <template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
        <tr>        
          <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.text"
            :class="['column sortable', pagination.descending ? 'desc' : 'asc', 
          header.value === pagination.sortBy ? 'active' : '']"
            @click="changeSort(header.value)"
          >
            <v-icon>arrow_upward</v-icon>
            {{ header.text }}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </template>
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr :active="props.selected" v-if="props.item.name=='USA'">

          <td>{{ props.item.name }} {{props.index}}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>        

        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Here is the Java Script:-

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      pagination: {
        sortBy: 'name'
      },
      selected: [],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Country',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'name'
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' }, 

      ],
      items: [
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'USA',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,       

        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'USA',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 129,
          calcium: '8%',
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Sweden',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          sodium: 337,
          calcium: '6%',
          iron: '7%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Sweden',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 413,
          calcium: '3%',
          iron: '8%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Sweden',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          sodium: 327,
          calcium: '7%',
          iron: '16%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Sweden',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          sodium: 50,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '0%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Sweden',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          sodium: 38,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '2%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Sweden',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          sodium: 562,
          calcium: '0%',
          iron: '45%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'USA',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          sodium: 326,
          calcium: '2%',
          iron: '22%'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'USA',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          sodium: 54,
          calcium: '12%',
          iron: '6%'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleAll () {
      if (this.selected.length) this.selected = []
      else this.selected = this.items.slice()
    },
    changeSort (column) {
      if (this.pagination.sortBy === column) {
        this.pagination.descending = !this.pagination.descending
      } else {
        this.pagination.sortBy = column
        this.pagination.descending = false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

so, in this case, the index should be **0 1 8 9** but I am getting **0 1 2 3** and when I use hide action the index I am getting is **6 7 8 9**

Can someone tell me how should I get correct index values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `{{items.indexOf(props.item)}}` instead of `{{props.index}}` to get the right index of item